# Get max value of third column after using groupby over two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have csv file with 3 columns ( CustomerID, Description, UnitPrice). I want to get the most valuable product (with maximal unit price ) that each customer bought, and its price.

I have downloaded database from here:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Online%20Retail

I wrote a code for that, and it works, but honestly I do not know why it works, and it looks kinda silly. 
I want to see as an end result table with all tree (CustomerID, Description and UnitPrice). Is there any better way to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

my_dataFrame = pd.read_csv("OnlineRetailNEW.csv", dtype={'CustomerID': object})

#the most valuable product that each customer bought, and its price
def get_most_valuable_product():

    most_valuable = my_dataFrame.groupby(["CustomerID", "Description"], sort=False)["UnitPrice"].max().reset_index()
    most_valuable = most_valuable.groupby(["CustomerID"]).max().reset_index()
    return most_valuable

print(get_most_valuable_product())
```

I have tried this , but It does not give me good results:

```
def get_most_valuable_product():

    most_valuable = my_dataFrame[["CustomerID", "Description", "UnitPrice"]].sort_values('UnitPrice').groupby(['CustomerID']).tail(1)
    return most_valuable

print(get_most_valuable_product())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_dataframe[[CustomerID, Description, UnitPrice]].sort_values('UnitPrice').groupby(['CustomerID']).tail(1)
```

If we sort by the price of the units, then groupby the id, the most expensive one will always be at the bottom of each customers group.

Comment: Ok, but I want to see only thse columns CustomerID, Description and UnitPrice

Comment: This will show you all of them, ohh there are more columns in your df that you want to hide? EDIT: Changed it so it will only show those three columns.

Comment: The problem is that this works, but It does not gives correct result: most_valuable.groupby(["CustomerID"]).third_column_name.max()

Comment: The only reason I can think that this wouldn't work is if the customer has 2 items both the same price. It would randomly have sorted them.

Comment: I took product description from result, found that product in my csv file , and the UnitPrice is not the same

Comment: Where are you putting it in your code? This can be directly used with my_dataframe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192122/discussion-between-aleksandar-and-ben-pap).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `most_valuable.groupby(["CustomerID"]).third_column_name.max()`

Comment: That would only give them the customer ID and max price. However, they want the product name as well.

Comment: Thats not what I want. I know that I can do that but I want to see all 3 columns as output

Answer (score 0):

You can use `idxmax`

```
maxids = my_dataFrame.groupby(['CustomerID', 'Description'].UnitPrice.idxmax()

my_dataFrame.loc(maxids.values)
```

Note that `idxmax` only gives you one record per group. If you want all records (multiple max), then use `transform`

```
maxvals = my_dataFrame.groupby(['CustomerID', 'Description'].UnitPrice.transform(lambda x: x.max())

my_dataFrame[my_dataFrame.UnitPrice == maxvals]
```